# PowerApps Filter function returns items with double quotes appended at the start and end of each row

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

In PowerApps, If I set the Items property of a combo box to a SharePoint list, it shows items in combo box alphabetically sorted way and also without any double quotes appended to the start and end of each record.
But, I need to filter out current user from the items for combo box.
I am using following formula to filter out current user in items property of combo box:

Filter('SharePoint List', userName <> User().FullName).

After I change items property to above code, it shows combo box items appended with double quotes and also alphabetical sorting goes away.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

If I use following formula, it works properly (But not what I want to achieve):
Filter('SharePoint List', userName = User().FullName)